# What are the Pros and Cons of using SXA?

Tags: sxa

The company I work for has purchased Sitecore XP1, and we will be basically starting from scratch to get all of our sites into Sitecore. I have been told that SXA is already included in our package, and the marketing team is really pushing for SXA to be used. As a developer, I am not liking what I have read about how it restricts development. Our main site is huge with a lot of custom and dynamic data/pages, and a lot of different api integrations. I'm not sure if having SXA will be a benefit to us. We have a really good development team with back-end devs, front-end devs, and a designer, and we are all pretty new to Sitecore in general.

What are you experiences with SXA?

What are the pros/cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the decision should be based on 
 1. Do you want to use the Sitecore ecosystem with full capabilities? Not only use Sitecore as a CMS but also follow the architectural and design practices.
 2. Use Sitecore as a CMS and build your custom stuff on top of it. This approach can lead us to develop certain features(functionality) that Sitecore offers out of the box. Also out custom implementation not really compatible with Sitecore ecosystem.

I would always recommend to go with SXA because it not only provides certain features out of the box but also drives us to follow the same architectural/design patterns. This can be very useful when the project grows.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Syed.  
The content editors were demoed SXA during the sales talks so they liked what they saw. Our dev team is against it because it seems like it won't really benefit anything except the drag/drop UI functionality, and seems like it might add a lot of time to the project to customize.  
Can't similar functionality be done with normal Sitecore using the Experience Editor for adding components into placeholders? We had already decided to build on Helix principles no matter what, and we could just SXA as a guide to model our components after.

Comment: Not sure which version of SXA you guys are on, the latest version does provide a lot of customization options.
If you have come across SXA component variants, with literally CSS you can change the whole website look and feel.
Coming back to using Sitecore and writing your own components using Helix principles, yes that is quite possible and people were doing that in past versions. But how much time it takes to hit the market is Considerable